# Qt Creator No CMake generators on raspberry pi

Tags: qt, cmake, raspberry-pi, qt-creator, raspbian

I have installed qt creator on raspberry pi. sudo apt-get install qtcreator. The program launches and seems to be working except when I load in a cmake project I cannot run cmake through qt creator because qt creator does not detect any cmake generators. When I run cmake -h from the command line there are many cmake generators listed. I want to use the standard Unix Makefiles generator. I have also checked that make is installed and working from the command line on my raspberry pi.

Other details:  Running the latest Raspbian, qt creator 2.5, qt 4.8.2,

Comment: You can set the path for the CMake executable in `Tools > Options > Build & Run > CMake`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but yes, I've got my cmake executable path set properly but it doesn't help find generators

Comment: I've also just encountered this very same problem with my new Raspberry Pi 2 (Raspbian + all installed software is up-to-date).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu after messing with my GCC installation. Maybe the following fix will also work on a Raspberry Pi:

1. Go to View -> Options -> Build & Run
2. Go to the "Kits" tab and make sure that a compiler is selected.
3. Go to the "CMake" tab and hit "Add" to specify the path to your cmake, e.g.`/usr/bin/cmake`. Do this even if the same path is already there as an autodetected cmake.
4. Select your newly added cmake and hit "Make Default".